# Has SharePoint 2007 SP3 really reached end of life?

Tags: 2007, support

Is SharePoint 2007 as a product and SP3 end-of-life? This [link](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=16496) of Microsoft Support Lifecycle seems to suggest so, but there are usually "extended extended support" options for paying customers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should still be extended support available to companies.  I actually still have clients that have paid support for Portal Server 2003.  With that said, at some point it becomes cost prohibitive and I would suggest you make every effort to start planning for an upgrade.

Comment: This is especially important since there is no direct upgrade path from 2007 to 2013 so you will have the added step of having to move your content through SP2010 as well

Comment: While there is no direct upgrade path, you always have the option of migrating with 3rd party tools.

Comment: Very true but those also have a history of leaving 'artifacts' as part of the migration that can cause issues down the road.  I've spent the better part of a year working with Microsoft on getting past two such instances of those that were introduced with two third party tools. YMMV but we certainly got bit

Comment: Great answers, but is there a hard stop for Microsoft support? I am trying to convince a customer not to build anything in SP2007 despite that it is the only currently deployed and approved SP version.

Comment: I think the extended support options run until 2015.  With that said, I agree that it is foolish to make an investment in new development on the 2007 platform at this time.  I recently had a situation where a customer was just now looking to upgrade from 2003 to 2007, and we had to discuss the extended support options and why it was such a really bad idea to not go to at least 2010.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good description of the effects of the end of Mainstream support on [MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvarro/archive/2012/10/09/life-cycle-wss-3-0-amp-moss-2007-move-to-extended-support.aspx).
**Summary**

- Free support for Enterprise Agreements is over
- Don't expect any updates unless you paid for support last year and can prove it's a security vulnerability
- You must be on Service Pack 3 to receive extended support